# Компоненты в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты, компоненты

Всем доброго времени суток. При изучении столкнулся с такой вот задачей, реализация компонентов в js.Есть задача

```
function module() {
    class Component{
        constructor(){}
        onInit(){

        }
        onPropsChanges(changes){

        }
        render(){

        }
    }

    return {
        Component
    }
}
```

метод onPropsChages должен реализовывать такое условие

```
let result;
const mod = module()
 const component = new mod.Component();
 component.onPropsChanges = function(changes) { result = changes }
 component.props = { name: 'Stan' }
console.log(result) // ({ name: 'Stan' });

be possible to return a property object, but its changes should not have an effect on the original, 

() => {
    const mod = module()
    const component = new mod.Component();
    component.props = { name: 'Bob' }
    const props = component.props;
    props.name = 'John';
    props.address = 'Some address';
    console.log(component.props) //({ name: 'Bob' })
});
```

Толком понятной информации не нашел, может кто посоветует нормальный источник с примерами ну и если можно показать как этот пример реализовать.

Comment: Возможно стоит попробовать react?

Comment: @Mrage, тут дело в том что используется чистый джс, никаких фреймворков

Comment: Прочитайте про [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) & [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Они вам здесь помогут. Ну и про глубокое копирование элементов тоже не помешает.